# Should I use suppose or suppose that?

Tags: that

> Suppose G is finite.

or

> Suppose that G is finite.

whats the difference?

Comment: What do easily available dictionaries such as [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/suppose) indicate?

Comment: I suppose it’s mainly a matter of style in that context.

Answer (score 0):

They're the same!

Use of suppose that and suppose is the same and this two sentences are correct too

Comment: And how is the poster to know whether your assertion is correct?